# jQuery Mobile - data-filter can't reload on AJAX postback

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I have a page that looks something like this:

```
<ul id="ulList" data-role="listview" data-filter="true" 
data-filter-placeholder="Find items" data-theme="none" class="List">
<li>Text 1</li>
<li>Text 2</li>
<li>Text 3</li>
</ul>
```

I can set the filter to automatically be "Text" by using this code:

```
$('.ui-input-text').val('Text');
```

That code populates the filter text box, however, the filter does not execute.

I tried using:

```
$('#List').listview('refresh');
```

But that did not work.

Any Thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using jQM 1.3.x, you can trigger the change event on the input:

```
$('.ui-input-search input').val('1').change();
```

If you are using jQM 1.4.x, you can use the **[refresh](http://api.jquerymobile.com/filterable/#method-refresh)** method on the filterable widget:

```
$("#ulList").filterable("refresh");
```

Comment: .change() !!!!!! Thank you!!!!

I had to add this to the code after a postback:

I also had to add a textbox to collect the value before the postback.

setTimeout(function () {  $(document).ready(function () {  $('.ui-icon-searchfield input').val($("#txtSearchFilter").val()).change();});}, 10);